# Ruby Stop ActiveRecord from converting mysql 0000-00-00 00:00:00 to nil

Tags: mysql, activerecord

I'm querying data from MySQL using ActiveRecord. However ActiveRecord converts following MySQL date `0000-00-00 00:00:00` to nil. I know it's an empty date but MySQL's validation is poor and will accept this for a non null column. This data needs to be ported back to MySQL and the row insertion will fail. Is it possible to make active record return the date as MySQL has it?

Comment: As you have pointed out, `0000-00-00 00:00:00` is not a valid date, so how do you expect an invalid date to be represented?

Comment: I know but MySQL dump still dumps it and thus getting back the same record is possible with MySQL dump. I want to achieve the same thing if possible.